# How Utilize of debugging tools in node js

Tags: node.js

How to utilize debugging tools and logging statements in Node.js to identify and resolve the issue causing the warning message about packets being out of order.

I have got the following warning message in node.js.

> "Warning: Got Packets out of order, Expected 13 but received 0 "

Code is deployed on both Windows and Linux servers, and the database is MySQL. but I have got a warning in only the Linux server.

Please help me out to debug and resolve the above warning.